# How to make a Card fill screen height?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Using `dash` to create a simple application with a left menu and a plot as the main output.

I've adjusted widths using the `md` option of `dbc.Col`, and this is working ok as I resize the browser window.

However I'm having issues adjusting the height. I would like the `Card(GRAPHS)` below to fill the available screen height. How to I do that?

I have a callback retuning a `plotly` figure to the tag `my-graph`. If I use the figure height property, it will be fixed and won't resize.

The default height coming from `dash`/`plotly` is making the figure to short.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

GRAPHS = [
    dbc.CardHeader(html.H5('header')),
    dbc.CardBody([dcc.Graph(id='my-graph')])
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container([
            dbc.Row([html.H1('title')]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([dbc.Card(LEFT_MENU)]),
                dbc.Col([dbc.Card(GRAPHS)])  # How to make this fill screen height?
])])])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone with more experience using `dash` could give you a better answer, but I think you can set up a specific vertical size for your cards using the keyword `style`. Then you can pass a dictionary with the arguments for CSS stylesheet, in this case we want to change the height so `{'height':'100vh'}`. I would try this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container([
            dbc.Row([html.H1('title')]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([dbc.Card(LEFT_MENU, style={'height':'100vh'})]),
                dbc.Col([dbc.Card(GRAPHS, style={'height':'100vh'})])  
])])])
```

You can play around with different `vh` values to see what fits best

Alternatively you can fit the cards into a `CardGroup` as explained in the [documentation](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/card/). That should force all the cards to have the same height:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container([
            dbc.Row([html.H1('title')]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.CardGroup([
                    dbc.Card(LEFT_MENU),
                    dbc.Card(GRAPHS)
                ]) 
            ])
    ])
```